# OpenSSH server limit local forwarding to only unix sockets

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

#### Problem: Limit SSH `-L` forwarding only to unix sockets

- SSH server S is a shared server inside a private network used by several users.
- Use-case: for each user I create a local unix socket to use to reach an unique destination (already done). User then should be able to local port forward it to their own machine: `local -> S -> destination`.
- Port forwarding is limited to only a local forwarding via `AllowTcpForwarding local` to minimize attack surface and unwanted lateral network movements ([man](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config)).
- I want to limit forwarding to the minimum. Only localhost, ideally only user local sockets, i.e., users could do only `-L 12345:/home/user/server-local.sock`.
- [PermitOpen](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitOpen) allows only `host:port` notation, i.e., it is not possible to allow only unix-sockets.
- Users are not allowed to interact with each other, i.e., connect to their respective forwarded ports (if ports are used instead of sockets).

#### Any ideas how to achieve this?

No optimal idea so far.

- socat could be used, i.e.,

  - `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8443,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:'ssh -T -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -A server socat "UNIX-CONNECT:/user/tmp.sock" STDIO'` but that limits only to one port forward per ssh connection
  - or, start a master ssh tunnel `ssh -M -S ctrl.sock -fnNT server` and then use it for one socat per forwarding fashion

    - `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8443,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:'ssh -A -S ctrl.sock server socat "UNIX-CONNECT:/user/tmp1.sock" STDIO'`
    - `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8444,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:'ssh -A -S ctrl.sock server socat "UNIX-CONNECT:/user/tmp2.sock" STDIO'`
- `AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand` could return `permit-open` on a new connection, limiting local fwding only to a specific `host:port` pairs. I could define disjoint port blocks per-user. Then I would have to socat it together on the server side.
- It would be ideal if OpenSSH server enables configuration to allow only socket forwarding, but it does not.
- SSH Plugin / iptables / selinux?

Thanks!

Comment: There's `AllowStreamLocalForwarding local` for this, but it's also affected by `AllowTcpForwarding` and `PermitOpen` which as you wrote won't accept a syntax to select just unix sockets. All tests I could think of require to *also* allow TCP even if only unix socket is wanted.

Comment: The best I could find was to use `ssh -M -S ctrl.sock -fnNT server` to open master session, then `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8443,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:'ssh -S ctrl.sock server socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT:/user/tmp.sock'`

Answer (score 0):

(should be a comment but limited space / formatting)

> PermitOpen allows only host:port notation, i.e., it is not possible to allow only unix-sockets.

According to the link you posted:

> An argument of none can be used to prohibit all forwarding requests

While the wording here implies that it would also block Unix domain sockets, the context is TCP domain sockets. Did you test this?

Comment: I did test this (see my comment about it): doesn't work. Probably because unix socket support was added later, and the use case wasn't considered in full.